# Interpolating data in a data.table object inside a function

Tags: r, function, data.table

I'm currently trying to transform a script which performs an interpolation in a data.table object (by group) into a function.

I have data in long format similar to this example:

```
   UniqueId  Time   Var1      Var2    Var3
1       Id1     0     10   "cat-a"       2
2       Id1     5     12   "cat-a"       4
3       Id1    10     14   "cat-a"       6
4       Id2     0      8   "cat-b"       3
5       Id2    10     16   "cat-b"      10
6       Id3     0      6   "cat-a"       4
7       Id3    10      9   "cat-a"       8
[...]
```

As you can notice, the number of entries for each UniqueId can differ. What I want to do is to extract all unique values of the "Time" column, and make sure that all UniqueIds have an entry for each one of them, by performing a linear interpolation for numeric variables while for factors or strings, as they do not change over time, I take the first value for each UniqueId and replicate it n times (where n = length(unique(Time)), resulting in something like this:

```
   UniqueId  Time   Var1      Var2    Var3
1       Id1     0     10   "cat-a"       2
2       Id1     5     12   "cat-a"       4
3       Id1    10     14   "cat-a"       6
4       Id2     0      8   "cat-b"       3
5       Id2     5     12   "cat-b"     6.5
6       Id2    10     16   "cat-b"      10
7       Id3     0      6   "cat-a"       4
8       Id3     5    7.5   "cat-a"       6
9       Id3    10      9   "cat-a"       8
[...]
```

As the data I'm working on can be rather large (several Go's), I decided to use the data.table package. My current code looks like this:

```
Time.Common <- unique(MyData[, Time])
Time.Common <- Time.Common[order(Time.Common)]


MyData[, mapply(function(colVals, colName) {
  if(colName == "Time"){ # If we are operating on the time column, we replace its values with those of Time.Common
    return(Time.Common)
  }
  if(is.factor(colVals) | is.character(colVals)){ # If we are working on character or factor columns, we just repeat the value "length(Time.Common)" times
    rep(colVals[1], length(Time.Common))}
  else { # If it's a numeric column, we perform an interpolation
    withCallingHandlers(approx(x      = .SD[,Time],
                               y      = colVals,
                               xout   = Time.Common)$y,
                        warning = function(w){invokeRestart("muffleWarning")})
  }
}, .SD, names(.SD), SIMPLIFY = FALSE), by = eval(expr = "UniqueId")] # The process is repeated for each unique key value
```

This code produces the expected results. The problem is that when I try to convert into a function, I can't make it work anymore, and as I'm not an expert of data.table, I don't understand where is the issue.

Here is the function:

```
interpolation <- function(Data, 
                          UniqueKey     = "UniqueId",
                          TimeCol       = "Time",
                          InterMethod   = "linear"){
  # Recovering all unique values of the time column
  Time.Common <- unique(Data[, get(TimeCol, inherits = F)])
  Time.Common <- Time.Common[order(Time.Common)]
  
  # Interpolating
  Data[, mapply(function(colVals, colName) {
    if(colName == TimeCol){ 
      return(Time.Common)
    }
    if(is.factor(colVals) | is.character(colVals)){
      rep(colVals[1], length(Time.Common))}
    else {
      withCallingHandlers(approx(x      = .SD[,eval(parse(text = TimeCol))],
                                 y      = colVals,
                                 xout   = Time.Common,
                                 method = InterMethod)$y,
                          warning = function(w){invokeRestart("muffleWarning")})
    }
  }, .SDcols = .SD, names(.SD), SIMPLIFY = FALSE), by = eval(parse(text = UniqueKey))]
}
```

It's pretty much the same code, except for the part where I pass column names as variables, where I have to use `eval(parse())` or `get()`.
This function does not produce errors when I use it, but does not perform an interpolation neither (my data remains unchanged). Could someone help me on this one and help me find my mistake ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the interpolation in data.table like this

```
MyData[,c(
  list(Time = Time.Common),
  lapply(.SD, function(col) approx(x = Time, y = col, xout = Time.Common)$y)
  ), by = c('UniqueId','Var2'), .SDcols = c('Var1','Var3')]
```

and maybe use `lapply(MyData,typeof)` to work out which columns I was going to interpolate (in .SDcols =) and which were in the key (to go in the by =)

Edited to add a generic function to do this, you can use other methods to choose which columns are the keys and which are to be interpolated, but ultimately you can just pass charcter vectors in the by and .SDcols arguments of data.table.

```
interpolation <- function(mydata, time_col) {
  col_types <- lapply(mydata[,-time_col,with=FALSE],typeof)
  interp_cols <- names(col_types)[col_types %in% c('double', 'integer')]
  key_cols <- names(col_types)[!(col_types %in% c('double', 'integer'))]
  mydata[,c(
    list(Time = Time.Common),
    lapply(.SD, function(col) approx(x = get(time_col), y = col, xout = Time.Common)$y)
  ),by=key_cols, .SDcols = interp_cols]
}
interpolation(MyData, "Time")
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the alternative ! The thing is that the dataset I'm working on has a lot more columns than that and the name of the key might not always be "UniqueId", so I still need to transform this code into a generic function. I guess that my problem comes from the fact that I don't know how to use/pass column names as arguments inside a function operating on a data.table object (it might be the "get()" or the "eval(parse())" that I'm not using properly ?).

Comment: I'd avoid using parse and eval in a data.table if you can. I've added a generic interpolation function to the answer which should be something like what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for you example, I gave your function a try unfortunately I get the same output as with mine: the data.table object comes out unchanged as no interpolation is done.

Comment: `MyData <- interpolation(MyData, "Time")` if you want to overwrite the original table. It produces your example output in the question.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks ! I though that because of the way data.table works, the operation would be directly performed on the data given as an input. Thanks again for your help !